# Tried to download League of Legends with a guide but ended up destroying my computer

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

I was trying to download League of Legends on my computer using a guide from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/5svd2k/an_uptodate_guide_on_installing_league_of_legends/?st=j1fm8nf9&sh=25bd440a) but something went wrong during the process. I turned off my computer for the night and the next day, my task bar was gone and everything on top went away.The only things left were my desktop files and background. I could get open chrome by using "open with" on a file but I couldn't open apps like Shutter (a screenshot application) and Inkscape (an art application).

Comment: It sounds like you could benefit in the future from looking into LVM. LVM is snapshots allow you [to create system restore points](http://bit.ly/2pavaXa) before making big system changes like the one you describe above. If the changes break your system, you can revert back to a snapshot you took before you broke your system. It's easiest to setup LVM during install (you might have without knowing), but [it can be done after](http://bit.ly/2ou6BGA). This doesn't help with your current situation, but it may be useful in the future. Be warned, LVM is a bit technical.

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu with Unity or do you use a different desktop. Assuming you're using Unity, it sounds like it may not be running. Try running `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop; sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity`

Comment: @b_laoshi I am not able to open terminal. Do you have a way to open terminal without UI? I'm not sure if I'm on Unity, I don't think I'm using unity.

Comment: Also Ctrl+Shift+T does not work

Comment: Try Alt+F2. If that gives you a windows that will let you run a command, try starting gnome-terminal from there. If that doesn't work, use Ctrl+Alt+F2 to get to a different virtual console. Run the commands there, and then `sudo reboot` to restart.

Comment: @b_laoshi I've gotten the Ctrl+Alt+F2 terminal to open, how do I open the gnome-terminal? Which commands would I need to open the gnome-terminal? By the way, I appreciate all this help! :D

Comment: @b_laoshi Also, I have confirmed that I am indeed using Unity, except all the interface is gone. Another note, when I boot my computer now, it's checking for disk errors and mounting my disks.

Comment: @b_laoshi when gnome-terminal is typed into the terminal, it returns: "Failed to parse argument; could not open display"

Comment: Problem resolved! I have fixed my computer with the commands you have given me! Any idea why Unity disappeared so I can handle this problem in the future?

Comment: I glanced through the guide you linked to and nothing jumped out at me that might have caused the problem you were experiencing. Glad you got it figured out. I posted my solution below as an answer so you can actually mark the question as solved. If there is anything missing from my solution, feel free to edit or comment so it's accurate.

Comment: @b_laoshi I'm also wondering why my computer is so slow. After a few days, my computer started checking for disk errors, and after that the computer was really slow. My internet was fine, as my other devices has perfect internet connection, but everything on my computer was very slow. It was also trying to mount drive u01 sometimes. I got frustrated with the speed once so I left it on for a few hours and when I came back everything was up to normal speed. Any ideas why this may happen?

Comment: I can't say for sure. There are many factors that could contribute to the behavior your seeing including but not limited to a failing hard disk or malware. If you don't have a [backup of your system/files](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem), make one. Also try [checking the SMART data](https://askubuntu.com/a/528077/606758) for you disks. It can't detect every type of disk failure, but if it detects problems with your disk, they should be addressed. Most of this is outside the scope of this question and might benefit from the posting of a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a clue why Unity would have been removed or corrupted. I can't really say that I know much about LOL, but something clearly happened to Unity along the way. The following steps should get Unity back up and running on your computer.

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to open a different virtual terminal console
- Once in this console run

  - `sudo apt-get update`
  - `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`
  - `sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity`
  - `sudo reboot`

The commands should reinstall Unity, fixing whatever is broken in you desktop environment. After reboot, you should be back in business.